# Unix "time" command with pipeline prints no time-report

Tags: command-line, unix, csh

Of the two C-shell aliases below, only the first prints the *time* command's report of elapsed time. How can I get the alias with the pipeline to also print the time report?

```
alias make1 'time make'

alias make2 'time make |& tee make.log'
```

Comment: @ArneStenström I approved the edit now – but please note that editing others' posts in such a radical way as proposed before (and now reflected in your comment) is *not encouraged*. Furthermore, you've already edited the question once. While I understand that you want to improve your posts more than once, please make your suggested edits count and only propose *one*. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *time* command built-in to the C shell (csh or tcsh) doesn't work with pipelines. To avoid this limitation, use the standalone **[time](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time)** command instead, which is usually found at /usr/bin/time (if it isn't, try `whereis time` to locate it).

Change `time` in your command-line to `/usr/bin/time` (or `/usr/bin/time -p`) or whatever the path to the time program is, and it should work.

---

*Why it didn't work:*

The C shell (like some other shells) has a built-in *time* command (see the [builtin](http://manpages.info/freebsd/builtin.1.html) manual page), which is used in preference to the non-builtin (standalone) time program:

```
% which time
time: shell built-in command.
%
```

and the [man page for csh](http://manpages.info/freebsd/csh.1.html) (actually tcsh on my system) states:

```
time [command]
   Executes command (which must be a simple command, not an alias,
   a pipeline, a command list or a parenthesized command list) ...
```

The /usr/bin/time command doesn't have this limitation, and neither do the inbuilt *time* commands of most other shells, for example bash or zsh.

Comment: where can I download non-csh time program? I've googled and it seems hard to find one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought /usr/bin/time is the built-in one and was trying to find another one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use a pipe there? What you're essentially doing is piping the result of the second `time` command into `tee`. That's why your result is not being printed out - it's actually probably being written into make.log.

Comment: it's not in the log either. I was wondering should I quote the command "make |& tee make.log"?

Comment: You should quote it as that's part of alias' syntax. Are you using BASH?

Comment: c shell. I will try quote the inner command.

Comment: Have you tried just piping the output? I don't know about c shell but check you've re-logged in after changing an alias so it can be reloaded.